# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of null in map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, immutable.js

I have findPlayerWithID function which return matched player id

```
function findPlayerWithID(players, id) {
  let i = 0;
  for (; i < players.count(); i++) {
        if (players.map((degisken) => degisken.get('id'))._tail === undefined) { continue; }

        if (players.map((degisken) => degisken.get('id'))._tail.array[i] === id) {
          return i;
        }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

But sometimes it give error in this line

```
 if (players.map((degisken) => degisken.get('id'))._tail === undefined) { continue; }
```

error is

```
gameStore.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of null
    at gameStore.js:38
    at immutable.js:3018
    at Ue.__iterate (immutable.js:2208)
    at r.__iterateUncached (immutable.js:3017)
    at F (immutable.js:606)
    at r.T.__iterate (immutable.js:322)
    at r.toArray (immutable.js:4260)
    at new Ue (immutable.js:2067)
    at _t (immutable.js:3572)
    at Ue.map (immutable.js:4403)
```

I think error because of null object
How can I check null in this line

```
if (players.map((degisken) => degisken.get('id')).




immutable.js:1317 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'merge' of null
    at immutable.js:1317
    at Ne (immutable.js:1973)
    at Ne (immutable.js:1982)
    at Ne (immutable.js:1982)
    at pe.updateIn (immutable.js:1280)
    at pe.mergeIn (immutable.js:1314)
    at gameStore.js:207
    at createReducer.js:15
    at combineReducers.js:133
    at c (createStore.js:178)
```

Updated
with @canaan-seaton answear I change
this

```
if (players.filter(degisken => degisken !== null).map((degisken) => degisken.get('id'))._tail.array[i] === id) {
          return i;
        }
```

this work 
but it give another error in immutablejs

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'merge' of null
    at immutable.js:1317
    at Ne (immutable.js:1973)
    at Ne (immutable.js:1982)
    at Ne (immutable.js:1982)
    at pe.updateIn (immutable.js:1280)
    at pe.mergeIn (immutable.js:1314)
    at gameStore.js:207
    at createReducer.js:15
    at combineReducers.js:133
    at c (createStore.js:178)
```

at this line in immutablejs

function(m ) {return typeof m.merge === 'function' ?

I searcg for that error
there is some info but I don't understand what should I do https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/597
here is my console
[image]

Comment: If you want to map players to their id's then you should use an object instead of an array with the key being the player id and the value being an object containing the player data. Your error indicates there are `null` values in your players array which i can't imagine is intended.

Comment: @trixn thanks..I edited question now it give immutableJS error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally , it is not a good practice to check for equality to `undefined`.

I would try to do it this way:
First of all, to make sure that `degisken` does exists you can go with `degisken && degisken.get(id)`

Second, you might want to use Object's hasOwnProperty method, which will be useful in here:

```
players.map((degisken) => {
   const id = degisken && degisken.get('id');
   if(id && id.hasOwnProperty('_tail') && id._tail.array[i] === id){
     return i
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to check if the array has elements then you can do something like the following....

`if (players && players.length > 0) {/* Do Stuff */}`

if you are concerned with specific indices within the array being null then you could do something like this....

```
if (players.filter(degisken => degisken !== null)
   .map((degisken) => degisken.get('id'))._tail === undefined)
   {/* Do Stuff */}
```

Comment: thanks.filter is work.I edited question now it give immutableJS error

Comment: with @matmiz answear it work and immutable not give error thanks